# System won't boot when xorg.conf exists

Tags: xorg, lubuntu, resolution, nvidia-optimus

### Problem:

I need to create a /etc/X11/xorg.conf file to get my graphics to work correctly, yet whenever I create one using `Xorg -configure` and place xorg.conf.new there, X won't start after a reboot.

### What I am doing that isn't working:

First I go into tty3 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>, then execute the following commands:

```
sudo stop lightdm
sudo Xorg -configure
sudo mv xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo reboot
```

After I reboot the system hangs on the plymouth boot screen, though the animation doesn't work (it just hangs with no dots filled).

I can still get into X by going into recovery mode, then selecting `resume normal boot`.

X still works perfectly well when I have deleted then `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file except for having 1024x768 resolution.

This is the terminal output of `sudo Xorg -configure`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5776296/

Here is the xorg.conf.new file that `sudo Xorg -configure` creates: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5776297/

### System Info:

I have an optimus system with a Sandybridge Mobile and a GeForce 555M.

I have this problem with LUbuntu 13.04, UbuntuGNOME 13.04, and regular Ubuntu 12.04, 12.10, and 13.04. All 64bit. Those are the only ones I am listing because those are the only ones that I have tested it on.

`lspci` output:

```
daboross:~ $ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF106M [GeForce GT 555M] (rev a1)
```

`xrandr` output:

```
daboross:~ $ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 800 x 600, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768        0.0* 
   800x600        61.0
```

Note that that `xrandr` output is when I had the `nomodeset` grub linux cmd parameter, and a newer `xrandr` output is below.

My screen resolution is 1366x768.

This happens with and without bumblebee, also it still happens in LUbuntu, UbuntuGNOME, and regular Ubuntu.

### Why I need xorg.conf:

Since installing LUbuntu, my screen has been using 1024x768 resolution instead of 1366x768, which is pretty annoying. I followed the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Monitor_or_Screens#Screen_resolution_is_wrong.2C_no_matter_what_I_do), but I can't get the creation of xorg.conf to work correctly.

### Edited info:

After removing `nomodeset` from grub's cmdline_linux, my resolution is back to normal.  It is now 1366x768 correctly.

`xrandr` output after removing `nomodeset`:

```
daboross:~ $ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

After removing `nomodeset`, I no longer need to create an xorg.conf file, though the problem persist that if I do create one, X won't start.

Comment: Add missing details: Which **Ubuntu** version? (12.04, 13.04) **32-bit** or **64-bit**? *I have had a similar issue (in last month), but without Nvidia card even being present.*

Comment: I have edited it. Do you use nomodeset?

Comment: No (or didn't touch that setting). I have had issue with 12.04, 12.10, 13.04 (all **64-bit**). I have a spare PC (same spec. except only 4GB, smaller HDD. I only fully resolved all performance / stability issues by adding Nvidia card **AND** clean re-install (12.04, 64-bit)). *I concluded that several things interacting caused these issues.*

Comment: ah. I have had the issue of not being able to create xorg.conf with all 64bit releases/flavors that I have tried on this computer. Until now though I haven't had any need to create one though so I didn't post anything about it. I haven't tried 32bit at all so I can't say if that works or not. Maybe I should install a 32bit version onto a small partition and see if I can create xorg.conf just to tell if it is an issue with that.

Comment: My understanding is that Ubuntu (since 12.04) automatically adjusts X-windows, on each startup. The **xorg.conf** file is only required to override that behaviour. That it can be suddenly required, or a dummy version created, is a **bug**.

Comment: Ye, I didn't need it until Lubuntu messed up, and the instructions I followed on the wiki told me to create one using that command. I don't need one anymore but would like to be able to create one in the future in case I need one.